# Selection sort using linked node, output is not correct [Java]

Tags: java

I use selectionSort to do sorting, and there is a swap function in selectionSort, however, the head's value in swap is not the same in the outside(after call function of selectionSort), thanks for response.

```
        public Node selectionSort(Node head){
        if(head == null)
            return head;
        Node min = head;
        Node beforeMin = null;
        Node ptr;
        for (ptr = head;ptr.next!=null;ptr = ptr.next)
        {
            if(ptr.next.value < min.value)
            {
                min = ptr.next;
                beforeMin = ptr;

            }
        }
            if(min != head)
                {swapNodes(head, head, min, beforeMin);}
            head.next = selectionSort(head.next);
            return head;

        }
    public void swapNodes(Node head, Node currX, Node currY, Node prevY)
    {
        // make 'currY' as new head
        head = currY;
        // adjust links
        prevY.next = currX;

        // Swap next pointers
        Node temp = currY.next;
        currY.next = currX.next;
        currX.next = temp;

    }
    }
```

**strong text**

Comment: What do you mean by, "not the same in the outside"? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean head's value didn't return to outside(after call swapNodes), I make a mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already determined, in Java, you cannot pass to a function a reference such that the function can modify the reference itself.  `head` in `selectionSort` is a reference to an object.  When `head` is passed into `swapNodes`, it passes in a reference to the object, not a reference to `head` in `selectionSort`.  So when you assign something to `head` in `swapNodes`, you are not changing `head` in `selectionSort`.

Two ways of dealing with this:

Option 1: Make `head` a property (member) of the class rather than a parameter to `swapNodes`. Then the `head` variable itself will be accessible from both methods.

```
public class YourClass {
    private Node head;

    public Node selectionSort { . . . }

    public void swapNodes { . . . }
}
```

Option 2: Create an object that contains `head` as a member and use that object everywhere, including passing it as the parameter.

In a case like yours, Option 1 is the obvious choice.